# how do i write a function that converts sample data (ex. 20010317) to date format MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: vba

I am given sample data in cells B18, B19, and B20 with dates in the form 20010317, 20120809, 20130430.

How do I write a function that will convert the dates into date format, MM/DD/YYYY.

I have to call this function "DateConverter", with one pass through variable "dtYYYYMMDD"

Than I have to fill in range C18 through C20 with the function to display results of converting range B18 through B20

```
Function DateConverter(SmplData As String) As Date
    'This function will convert the sample data to date format
    DateConverter = DateSerial(Left$(SmplData, 4), Mid$(SmplData, 5, 2), Right$(SmplData, 2))
End Function
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: To be honest I am absolutely clueless right now. I just started learning this about a week ago. This is how far I got and I do not even know if it is correct.

Comment: Function DateConverter(SmplData As String) As Date
'This function will convert the sample data to date format

DateConverter = DateSerial(Left$(SmplData, 4), Mid$(SmplData, 5, 2), Right$(SmplData, 2))

End Function

Comment: How about searching this site? There are already plenty of answered questions about converting date formats in Excel/VBA. I'm sure you can adapt one of those to suit your requirement.

Comment: Please add sample code to the question, much easier to read there...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. The following code will take the numbers entered in the cells listed above, convert them and display the newly formatted date into the cells next to it.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call DateConverter
End Sub

Public Function DateConverter()
Dim dtYYYYMMDD As Range
Dim NewDate As Date

Set dtYYYYMMDD = Range("B18:B20")

For Each cell In dtYYYYMMDD
    NewDate = Mid(cell, 5, 2) & "/" & Right(cell, 2) & "/" & Left(cell, 4)
    cell.Offset(0, 1) = NewDate
Next

End Function
```